# Assign a converter to a member of ancestor for binding in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, converters

I wanted to know how to assign my converter to a member called `ConvertPoint` in the ancestor `Viewport`?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestShape}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <RelativeSource AncestorType="{x:Type root:Viewport}" x:Key="Viewport"/>
        <root:BezierScaleConvertor x:Key="BezierScaleConvertor" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <control:TestShape>
        <control:TestShape.StartPoint>
            <MultiBinding Converter="???"> <----------- Here I don't know how to refer to the member ConvertPoint which is a convertor in Viewport, if I use dynamicResource or Binding, it will raise an exception because it's not a DP.
                <Binding Path="StartPoint" />
                <Binding Path="ScaleX" RelativeSource="{StaticResource Viewport}"/>
                <Binding Path="ScaleY" RelativeSource="{StaticResource Viewport}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </control:TestShape.StartPoint>
        <control:TestShape.Segments>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BezierScaleConvertor}">
                <Binding Path="Segments" />
                <Binding Path="ScaleX" RelativeSource="{StaticResource Viewport}" />
                <Binding Path="ScaleY" RelativeSource="{StaticResource Viewport}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </control:TestShape.Segments>
    </control:TestShape>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it out.

To 100% make this cas works, you should use c# code version of datatemplate.

That's all.